# How to add premium subscriptions for commands in discord.py bot?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am thinking of adding a premium subscription to my bot for some commands . The only way striking my head right now is i should make a payments page with any service like razorpay or something and make a list of user id's for users who'll able to access those commands and make a custom check for each command.

Something like this:

```
list = [user id]
def user_is_premium(ctx):
    return ctx.message.author.id in list
```

But that thing'll be manual and I need to personally add user id's into list. Is there a way I can skip this hassle and make something where users will pay and their id's will automatically  be added or something like that , something better than this custom check stuff.

Remember, I am talking about subscription not one time payment so users will be need to renew their subscription per month for continuous access.

Comment: - Link into an api for subscription or work off roles and Patreon (Its not to hard). Other things work but whatever you want
- Use a database for continuous data (saving its state across restarts n such)
- Update your list on start with the database

Easy peasy, hope this general idea helps

Comment: Decorate your premium command with a check that checks if the user has a given role: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=check#discord.ext.commands.check
Use a service that adds roles to a user after payment. E.g. Patreon like Ethan said.  
Alternatively if you are confident make your own website that interfaces with a payment API. Add the users automatically to a database and make your bot interface with that database.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a database of some type `firestore` might be a good option with the free tier. Alternatively, you can use a google sheet.

You should use [zapier](https://zapier.com/) as a way to automate it for you, if you don't want to do it your self.

The trigger should be the email you get for payment and with the discord name. Add it to the database and read it in your bot by using `docs = db.collection(ctx.guild.id).where('name', '==', ctx.author.name)` and check if expiration date is in the future. You can also convert that to id's.

This might not be the perfect solution but it should be east to implment all you need is to set the trigger right